# React - How to adjust body padding based on height changes of children within a sticky header?

Tags: reactjs, sticky

I have a page with a `<Header />` and `<BodyContainer />` components. The header is sticky and floating above the content of the body, i.e. it is fixed to the top of the viewport and has a z-index. This means that the BodyContainer requires some top padding equal to the height of Header in order to prevent the header from obscuring the content beneath it. This height needs to be set dynamically - when the height of Header changes, so does the top padding of BodyContainer. The issue I have is that Header also has child components, whose heights can change dynamically which, in turn, will affect the overall height of the Header.

One solution is for any child component of Header to fire a redux action (using `componentDidUpdate`) to update a specific store state.  BodyContainer can connect to the store state and detect when this value changes, get the new height of the Header and update its top padding to the same height.

Is there any alternative method of achieving the same?

Answer (score 0):

If the both are wrapped in the same component then add a property on `Header` like `onHeightChange` that will have a function called each time the height change. Then in `BodyContainer` add a method like `updatePadding` that will be call by the function pass in `onHeightChange` with the new height.
Example:

```
class Wrapper extends React.Component {
    onHeightChange = (newHeight) => {
        if(this.bodyContainer) this.bodyContainer.updatePadding(newHeight);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
               <Header onHeightChange={this.onHeightChange} />
               <BodyContainer ref={c => this.bodyContainer = c} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}


class Header extends React.Component {
    componentDidUpdate() {
         if(this.props.onHeightChange) this.props.onHeightChange(/*new height*/);
    }
}

class BodyContainer extends React.Component {
    updatePadding = (newHeight) = > {
         // Do your stuff 
    }
}
```

Comment: In this example, `onHeightChange` will not be triggered by a change in the children of `Header`. But I guess this is a simple method of passing this down as a prop to the children. Maybe firing a redux action from the children would be appropriate and have BodyContainer simply listen to that store state change?

Comment: Yeah! That was just an example! You may call onHeightChange where you want! But using the store is also a good idea. Or you can use the React Context API! I wrote an article to how to use it rather than Redux store for everything https://medium.com/p/e6d96ca8abca?source=linkShare-1d75ea07b723-1537875626